# pandas grouby problems: merge two rows in one dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, pandas-groupby

I need to merge all rows with the same index in one dataframe. I got a solution in stack overflow, but I met some problems:

```html
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

three = {'name':['ming', 'viper', 'rookie'], 'year':[1997, 1998, np.nan]}
one = {'name':['rookie'], 'year':[1995]}
df3 = pd.DataFrame(three, index=['rng', 'edg', 'ig'])
df2 = pd.DataFrame(one, index=['ig'])
df_concat = pd.concat([df2, df3])
print(df_concat)
```

df_concat is:

[image]

I use grouby() method in this way:

```html
df_g = df_concat.groupby(level=0, sort=False).sum()
print(df_g)
```

Howver, the result is not what i expected:
[image]

Why the 'name' column is lost?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try via `agg()`:

```
df_g=df_concat.groupby(level=0, sort=False).agg({'name':'first','year':'sum'})
```

output of `df_g`:

```
       name     year
ig     rookie   1995.0
rng     ming    1997.0
edg     viper   1998.0
```

**Note:** In this code `df_concat.groupby(level=0, sort=False).sum()` since the values in name column is not a numeric so this is not including values of name column and performing `sum()` on year